# Update information without creating new line in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

The script I had been working on reads all folders on the CD-ROM drive "i" and searches for mp3 files, copying them onto the destination "e:\MP3\new".

```
@ECHO off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd /d "i:\"
set count=1
for /r %%d in (*.mp3) do (
     set /a count+=1
     )
echo There were %count% files found

set countb=1
for /r %%g in (*.mp3) do (
     set /a countb+=1 
     echo|set /p = File: !countb!/%count% 
     copy "%%g" "e:\MP3\new" > nul
)

endlocal
```

Let´s suppose in this example that 115 files were found.

**What I get from the above code:**

There were 115 files found 
File: 1/115 File: 2/115 File: 3/115 File: 4/115 File: 5/115 (...) File: 115/115

**What I want:**

There were 115 files found 
File: X/115

*where X  will be constantly updated on the screen each time an mp3 file is successfully copied*

Any help to fix that?

Comment: What have you written and tried in achieving that goal? _Your question currently looks like an off topic code request!_

Comment: @Compo I have written all the script from scratch and tried several combinations but none have yielded the "What I want" result.

Comment: You need to move the cursor. There are several ways to do that. It should be easy to search/select one method.

Comment: You should first replace `echo|` by `< nul` + _space_; then you need the _carriage-return_ character to move the cursor back on the same line...

Comment: If your using windows 10, ANSI escape codes can be used to position the cursor, clear the line and print from the chosen position. <esc>[1;1H will reposition the cursor to line 1 column 1. <esc>[K will clear the line from that point. All together: ECHO <esc>[1;1H<esc>[K "Your Message".

<esc> represents the ANSI escape character.

Comment: @T3RR0R I tried to follow your tips by opening a new bat file in notepad and added the following: `@echo off  echo <esc>[1;1H<esc>[07m<esc>[K<esc>[1;55H Hello world`. I receive a message "system cannot find the file specified". I typed the "dir" command on the directory and can clearly see the file right there. How to use it then?

Comment: Do confirm the following: 
1, You substituted the <esc> with the appropriate ANSI escape character.
2, Your using windows 10 (Version 1511 or newer)

If both are true, your message should print  as expected.
Here's a paste with the correct ANSI code, just in case your missing it:
https://pastebin.com/GCdbStbM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you are initialising your counters wrongly, they should be set to zero (like `set count=0`) rather than one to get the correct numbers.

Secondly, you should replace `echo|set /p =` by `< nul set /P =`, because the pipe (`|`) is slower than simple (input) redirection (`<`) since it creates new `cmd` instances for either side.

To move the cursor in the Command Prompt window back to the beginning of the current line, you need to write the carriage-return character first. However, you cannot use this character as the first one with `set /P`, because it is going to be removed, together with other leading white-space characters. So you need another invisible character preceding the carriage-return that is not going to be removed; let us choose the back-space character.

Therefore, the fixed code may look like this, for instance:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem // Gather the back-space character:
for /F %%B in ('prompt $H ^& for %%Z in ^(.^) do rem') do set "BS=%%B"
rem // Gather the carriage-return character:
for /F %%C in ('copy /Z "%~f0" nul') do set "CR=%%C"

cd /D "I:\"
set /A "count=0"
for /R %%d in ("*.mp3") do (
    set /A "count+=1"
)
echo There were %count% files found.

set /A "index=0"
for /R %%g in ("*.mp3") do (
    set /A "index+=1"
    < nul set /P ="%BS%!CR!File: !index!/%count%"
    copy "%%~g" "E:\MP3\new\" > nul
)

endlocal
```

Comment: Just great! Thank you a lot for your time and explanations. Could you please also tell me : 1 - why you used quotation marks on `".mp3"` ? ; 2 - why quotation marks on `set /A "index+=1"` ? ; 3- why `"%%~g"` instead of `"%%g"` ?; 4- what does `^(.^) do rem`  mean?

Comment: You're welcome! Well, it's not necessary in this situation to use quotation marks (around `*.mp3`), but in general paths should be enclosed in such as they may contain spaces or other special characters; that's why I also did it here; `%%~g` in this context removes potential surrounding quotes, so this makes sure there is no double-quotation...

Comment: The quoted `set` syntax is safe against special characters (like `set "VAR=Value"` or `set /A "VAR=Integer"`), the quotes are not part of the value; note that this requires [Command Extensions](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) to be enabled, but they are as per default anyway...

Comment: The `^` is the escape character in batch scripting and it ensures that the closing `)` of the inner `for %%Z` loop is not recognised by the outer `for /F %%B` loop; otherwise, a syntax error would arise as the outer loop appered to be incomplete...